# .NET Datamatrix barcoding components?

Tags: components, barcode

Can anyone recommend a .NET component that can create and read datamatrix barcodes? I will be using the barcode for a project that will be sending and receiving the barcode on a fax coversheet. I have found a few compents out there but was wondering if anyone has had good experiences or recommnedations.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using datamatrix.net
It's working well for me.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/datamatrixnet/

http://datamatrixnet.sourceforge.net/

If you or anybody knows other libraries for .net, let me know.